# How to verify that a reward address is associated with a public staking key?

Tags: cardano-address, nami-wallet

I'm attempting to verify Nami wallets. The scheme is something like this:

1. Server sends a nonce to frontend
2. User signs the nonce using their reward address `cardano.signData(rewardAddress, nonce)`
3. The signature is sent back to the backend to be verified.

I've managed to do all these steps, including verifying that the nonce has been correctly signed by a given key. But I can not figure out how to make sure that the key the message is signed with corresponds to the address they have given me.

I have to either extract the public key from the reward address or construct the reward address from the public key.

In the @emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser they do this:

```
const stakeKeyHash = this.headers.address.hash();
const reconstructedAddress = RewardAddress.new(
   checkAddress.network_id(),
   StakeCredential.from_keyhash(stakeKeyHash)
);
```

...but I'm using Haskell so I have to do it on my own

network_id seems to be one of the strings "Mainnet" or "Testnet"